# Dynamically create variables in ruby

Tags: ruby

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
while i < 3 do
    puts i
    @b[i] = Benchmark.new
    i += 1
    @a += 1
end

puts "Here is a #{@a}"
puts @b0.inspect
puts @b1.inspect
puts @b2.inspect
```

Sadly, it doesn't work at all. []= is regarded as an unrecognised method!

Comment: No reason at all for vote down. Made an effort to solve my own problem. Did in-fact actually solve it. Was a told a better way to solve it by a Stackoverflow user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `instance_variable_set`

```
3.times{|i| instance_variable_set "@x#{i}", i }
@x1 # => 1
@x2 # => 2
```

Though for this particular task you should use arrays, it's a rookie mistake to use lots of variables instead of lists.

```
benchmarks = []    
n.times { benchmarks << Benchmark.new } # or benchmarks = (0..n).map { Benchmark.new }
benchmarks.each do |bm|
  # do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly a job for an array, not for many instance variables.

```
benchmarks = number.times.map { Benchmark.new }
puts "Here is a #{number}"
benchmarks.each { |b| puts b.inspect }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question! The eval method is the answer:

```
puts "Welcome to Benchmark 1.0! How many benchmarks do you wish to perform? (We recommend three)"
number = gets.chomp.to_i
@a = 0
i = 0
while i < number do
    puts i
    eval("@b#{i} = Benchmark.new")
    i += 1
    @a += 1
end

puts "Here is a #{@a}"
puts @b0.inspect
puts @b1.inspect
puts @b2.inspect
```

Comment: But why? This send needlessly complicated for something that already has data structures.

Comment: Hence why I've asked!  :)